# Finding closures in a DB table of a given depth with SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, closures, transitive-closure-table

I have the following table: ( I am using sqlite)

```
.schema T 
CREATE TABLE T (i TEXT, j TEXT, v INTEGER);

select * from T;

i |j |v
x |y |1
x |z |1
y |a |1
z |b |1
a |c |1
c |d |1
```

I need to find the closure of a particular `i` to a given depth. However, with SQLite I can't use recursive queries. I tried writing one query but can't invoke it efficiently to get the desired result:

```
sqlite> Select i,j,v  FROM T WHERE i='x'

...> union

...> SELECT R.i "i",T.j "j",R.v+t.v "v" FROM T JOIN T as R ON R.j=T.i where R.i='x';

i|j|v
x|a|2
x|b|2
x|y|1
x|z|1
```

This lists all the closures to a depth of 2. But in my particular use case I need to allow for closures up to a depth of 8.

With this types of query I can try:

```
SELECT   i,j,v FROM T WHERE i='x'

union

SELECT R.i "i",T.j "j",R.R.x+T.v "x" FROM T JOIN (SELECT R.i,T.j,R.v+T.v "x" FROM T JOIN T AS 
R ON R.j=T.i where R.i='x') AS R ON R.j=T.i where R.i='x'

union

SELECT R.i "i",T.j "j",R.v+T.v "x" FROM T JOIN T AS R ON R.j=T.i where R.i='x';

i|j|v
x|a|2
x|b|2
x|c|3
x|y|1
x|z|1
```

This will return closures to a depth of 3, but with redundant select queries. Is there a better way to find the closures?